# using GCM service, the app stucks while acquiring wakelock

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-wake-lock

There is only one package in the app. I have seen other solutions but it is not working in my case. Please help. The process always get stuck at the wakelock.

```
 package com.examples.majorlogin;
import static com.examples.majorlogin.CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID;
import static com.examples.majorlogin.CommonUtilities.displayMessage; 
import android.app.Notification; import android.app.NotificationManager;     
import android.app.PendingIntent; 
import android.content.Context; import android.content.Intent; import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device registered
     **/
    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
        displayMessage(context, "Your device registred with GCM");
        Log.d("NAME", MainActivity.name);
        ServerUtilities.register(context, MainActivity.name, MainActivity.email, registrationId);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device un registred
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
        ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Receiving a new message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on receiving a deleted message
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
        String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
        displayMessage(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Error
     * */
    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        // log message
        Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error,
                errorId));
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }

    /**
     * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
     */
    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      //  Notification notification = new Notification(icon,message,when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
      //  notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("New mail from ")
                .setContentText("hello")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.a1)
                .build();

    /*   Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setAutoCancel(false);
        builder.setTicker("this is ticker text");
        builder.setContentTitle("WhatsApp Notification");
        builder.setContentText("You have a new message");
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setContentIntent(intent);
        builder.setOngoing(true);
        builder.setSubText("This is subtext...");   //API level 16
        builder.setNumber(100);
        builder.build();
        NotificationManager manager;
        Notification myNotication;
       manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     myNotication = builder.getNotification();
       manager.notify(11, myNotication);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;*/
       // notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
       // notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        noti.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        noti.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);            

    }

}
```

> manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.examples.majorlogin"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="18"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission
    android:name="com.examples.majorlogin.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.examples.majorlogin.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SearchActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
...
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.examples.majorlogin" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name="com.examples.majorlogin.GCMIntentService"/>
</application>
```

I am not understanding what is the problem, please help.

Comment: From which package are you registering for gcm?

Comment: in the same package  "com.example.majorlogin"

Comment: any logs that can be helpful to debug?

Comment: I updated the library n problem got solved..thanx